# Fails to use `git check-ignore` from `subprocess.run`

Tags: python, git

I don't achieve to use `git check-ignore` from `subprocess.run`. What I have missed in the following not working example?

```
tools-for-dev > python
Python 3.8.11 (default, Aug  6 2021, 08:56:27)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from subprocess import run
>>> run(['git', 'a'])
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   src2prod/README.md
    modified:   src2prod/src/project.py
    modified:   src2prod/tools/debug/lof.py

CompletedProcess(args=['git', 'a'], returncode=0)
>>> run(['git', 'check-ignore', '**/*'])
CompletedProcess(args=['git', 'check-ignore', '**/*'], returncode=1)
>>> quit()
tools-for-dev > git check-ignore **/*
multimd/changes/x-todo-x.txt
spkpb/changes/x-todo-x.txt
spkpb/dist
spkpb/dist/spkpb-0.0.10b0-py3-none-any.whl
spkpb/dist/spkpb-0.0.10b0.tar.gz
...
```

Comment: does check ignore work without python? Looks like git returns non zero exit code. I would try run it first in CMD, then check exit code by running `echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%`

Comment: git works. See my list line of "code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very ugly patch... **See the 1st comment below for a better approach.**

```py
from os import popen

depth = 10 # <-- Just for the example but in real use
           # this value must be found automatically.

for i in range(-1, depth + 1):
    if i == - 1:
        pathsearch = '**'
    else:
        pathsearch = '**' + '/**'*i + '/*'

    filesfound = popen(f'git check-ignore {pathsearch}').read()

    if filesfound:
        print(filesfound)
```

Comment: You can use Python's own `glob.glob` or similar to collect up the path names to feed to `git check-ignore`, or you can use `shell=True` with its attendant problems (see the Python documentation). Note that not all shells expand `**` the way you would like, too, so probably best to use `glob.glob`.

Comment: @torek You are right. That is the approach I have decided to use in my project. I leave my answer as it even if it is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

<del>I am not sure but I think that the `run` command takes the first parameter given and encloses all the others with single quotes.</del>  As @torek pointed out in the comments, `run` command does not enclose arguments with quotes. Instead, [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) is called with `shell=False` if not specified otherwise. If the shell is not called in the first place, shell expansion cannot happen.

Again, as @torek observed, the best solution is probably using [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob), with the option `recursive=True` in your case, since you have the `**` pattern.

---

`check-ignore` does not work with [glob patterns](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_pattern), but with plain paths. If in the repository you were able to create a file called `**/*`, then it would probably find it (without shell expansion), but since you cannot do it, the only possible result is

> Exit Code 1: None of the provided paths are ignored.

Comment: Close, but not exactly. :-) You have the correct problem (that `check-ignore` does not take patterns) but `run` doesn't actually *add* quotes; it's that `run` has `shell=False` as the default, so that it doesn't *pass the whole thing through a shell* in the first place.